# Change content of top panel Opencart 1.5.5.1

Tags: opencart

I want change content of top panel in Opencart 1.5.5.1 (if you look at this site http://demo.opencart.com/ I mean this gray panel on top with category items "Desktops, Laptops & Notebooks..."). For example I want put to this panel information. I tried found it in administration, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply, without some editing of core files you aren't going to be able to do this. These items are categories only and are editable from the category editor under the option "Top" as in show in top menu. Information does not have this